# How to split webpage into "sections"

Tags: html, css

I'm making a "contact us" page and here I have three different people to contact.

The way I am designing this page is as such:

......................................................

*Name*

Left hand side = Contact Details, Right hand side = picture.

*Next person*

.....................................................

At the moment, I gave the pictures a class=profile and coded into my .css file:

```
.profile {
  float = right
}
```

However all this seems to have done is pushed my image to the right, like I want it, but now all the text is all bunched up and wrapping underneath.

I want all the pictures to be the same size (width = 700px, height - 440px) which I have coded into my html and I want this height to define the size of each "section".

How do I go about

a) Keeping the text to the left and not wrapping underneath and
b) Stopping it from all bunching up?

My initial idea was to put a load of line breaks in but I feel like there has to be a neater way in .css?

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/kaish/c9kaxLLh/

Hi all, that is the link to my jsfiddle showing my HTML and .css coding.

Since posting this, the client want a Google Map of their office instead of their profile picture so I have amended the images slightly but the same issue still holds. I want the map on the right and the contact details on the left and for each three clients I want it to be split into invisible "sections".

Comment: can you post your code? Also can you create a jsfiddle that way it will be easy to give you a solution, Also it should be `float : right` not `float = right`

Comment: How do I link my jsfiddle here?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ so here you an write your html CSS javascript and replicate your issue. You can save you code snippet and provide the link

Comment: Thanks @Reddy, I have added and edited my question :)

Comment: You need to supply your HTML and CSS here. There is no guarantee that jsfiddle will be available in the future. Note: the `<small>` is obsolete HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this

```html
<style>
.parent
{
 width:100%;
}
.left
{
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:5px;
 border:#CCC solid 1px;
 min-height:200px;
}

.right
{
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:5px;
 border:#CCC solid 1px;
 min-height:200px;
}

</style>

<div class="parent">

 
    <div class="left">
         
        some details
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        some image
    </div>
 


<div>
<!--parent ends-->
```

**Now if i take your codes inside my boxes**

```html
<style>
.parent
{
 width:100%;
}
.left
{
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:5px;
 border:#CCC solid 1px;
 min-height:200px;
}

.right
{
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:5px;
 border:#CCC solid 1px;
 min-height:200px;
}

</style>

<div class="parent">

 
    <div class="left">
         
        <h3>Form 1</h3>
        <form action="form" method="get">
        
        <input name="" type="text" /><br />
        <textarea name="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
        
        </form>
        <hr style="border-top:#CCC solid 1px; width:100%" />
        
        <h3>Form 2</h3>
               <form action="form" method="get">
        
        <input name="" type="text" /><br />
        <textarea name="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
        
        </form>
        <hr style="border-top:#CCC solid 1px; width:100%" />
        
      <h3>  Form 3</h3>
               <form action="form" method="get">
        
        <input name="" type="text" /><br />
        <textarea name="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
        
        </form>
       
        
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        
        <!--your code starts-->
        <div class="contact_location">
<h3>Employee #1</h3>

<div class="map"><script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:440px;">


<div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:440px;"></div>

<div>
<small><a href="http://embedgooglemaps.com">embed google maps </a></small>
</div>

<div>
<small><a href="http://freedirectorysubmissionsites.com/">link directories</a></small></div>

<style type="text/css">#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}
</style>

</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:17,center:new google.maps.LatLng(50.402068577896536,-4.185562806082097),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.402068577896536,-4.185562806082097)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>St Beaudeux News</strong><br>628 Wolseley Rd<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>

</div>

  <p> <b> Address </b></p>      
        
       <!-- your code ends-->
        
    </div>
 


<div>
<!--parent ends-->
```

Comment: Hi, this is almost perfect. This splits the text and images on both sides of the page correctly.

However the righting still bunches up (vertically) on the left hand side, how do I do this so when I finish my parent class, the next parent class starts underneath the longest item, be it the picture or the writing?

Comment: @Kaish It is great to be of some help. thumbs up

Comment: @Kaish what if we change this part to percentages `<div style="overflow:hidden;height:auto;width:100%;">`

Comment: @Kaish the width spoils the party: try defining the height alone and remove the width i.e. `height:440px;`